# Cannot import distutils from within a py2exe-compiled script

Tags: python, virtualenv, py2exe, distutils

I am on Windows Server 2012R2, trying to compile a script with py2exe, within a virtualenv, and I'm getting issues whenever one of the application scripts tries to "import distutils" (in my case, it's somewhere inside a 3rd-party library, but I reduced the problem here).

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a virtualenv

  ```
  virtualenv venv
  call venv\Scripts\activate
  ```
- Install py2exe inside the virtualenv

  ```
  easy_install --always-unzip py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe
  ```
- Create setup.py

  ```
  from distutils.core import setup
      try:
          import py2exe
      except:
          pass

  setup(
      console=[
          'py2exe_distutils.py'
      ]
  )
  ```
- Create py2exe_distutils.py

  ```
  import distutils
  ```
- Run py2exe

  ```
  python setup.py py2exe
  ```
- Try to run the generated executable

  ```
  dist\py2exe_distutils.exe
  ```

It returns:

```
    C:\Users\root\p\dist\library.zip\distutils\__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "py2exe_distutils.py", line 6, in <module>
        import distutils
      File "distutils\__init__.pyc", line 25, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name dist
```

The script runs fine when I run it directly (python py2exe_distutils.py), even from within the virtualenv.

Am I trying to do something unsupported by py2exe, or is something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Does it only happen when you try to compile from a virtualenv? I can't reproduce that behavior myself. I think I'm on a newer version of py2exe than yours shows though - you can get the latest via svn over on sourceforge.  Also, what's the output of your call to `python setup.py py2exe` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem while creating an executable that used [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) 0.12.0. This worked for me: before you create the executable, copy the `distutils` folder from the base python installation

```
robocopy C:\Python27\Lib\distutils venv\Lib\distutils /E /COPY:DAT
```

I am using virtualenv 12.0.4 and py2exe 0.6.6 on Windows 7 Professional. Some extra insight can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247130/cxfreeze-missing-distutils-module-inside-virtualenv). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33438148) pointed me in the direction of just copying the files.